# Why doesn't android studio always warn about calling methods which throw exceptions?

Tags: java, android, exception

In some cases, android studio lets me call a method which throws an exception, without a try/catch. Why is that? How can I enforce it to always warn me about it?

Comment: Could you please add an example?

Comment: My problem is that I don't know the way to reproduce... for some methods where the signature indicates ```throws```, it gives me an error for using it without try/catch, for some it doesn't

Comment: Maybe it does not warn you because they are unchecked exceptions https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html

Comment: Yeah, this is the difference between checked and unchecked examples. Checked examples are checked at compile time, so AndroidStudio not only *warns* you about the exception, it wouldn't even compile if you to not handle it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Two kinds of exceptions

**Checked Exceptions** are those that are inherited from the `Exception`class, you will be warned

**Unchecked Exceptions** are inherited from `RuntimeException`, calling a method that throws them will never show a compiler warning, but as the name suggest "just" mess it up at runtime ;-)

---

Here a short list of common exceptions, to help you weary restless searching fellows out ...

#### UNCHECKED exceptions

- StackOverflowError
- RuntimeException
- ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
- ClassCastException
- IllegalArgumentException
- IllegalStateException
- NullPointerException
- NumberFormatException
- AssertionError
- ExceptionInInitializerError
- NoClassDefFoundError

#### CHECKED exceptions

- Exception
- ClassNotFoundException
- CloneNotSupportedException
- FileNotFoundException
- ParseException
- InstantiationException
- InterruptedException
- IOException
- NoSuchFieldException
- NoSuchMethodException

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be about checked/unchecked Exceptions, as @RubioRic and @Altoyyr said. I didn't know about the difference.

Answer (score 0):

For the exception you can handle, use

```
try{
    //your business logic
}catch(Exception e) {
    //Err handling logic
}
```

For the exception you cannot handle, do not use an empty try/catch block, but use throws exception instead. Let the custom error handler you wrote to handle it from outer class etc.

```
//business logic which you know it will throw certain kind of exception
throw XException("your err descrption");
```

The last case is you don't even know what happened, please fix the code according to the exception/ err trace, it is a bug where business logic should handle well.

Please read about the error handling in java throught this link:
http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/11/19/exceptions.html